# text justify is not working correctly with RichText in arabic language

Tags: dart, flutter, arabic, richtext

I am using RichText and in this text justify is not working correctly with RichText when using any of number in text span with, but working fine without the number in string

```
RichText(
            softWrap: true,
            textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
            text: TextSpan(
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                fontSize: 16.0,
              ),
              children: getSpan(),
            ),
          ),
```

```
 List<TextSpan> getSpan() {
    List<TextSpan> spans = List<TextSpan>();
    spans.add(TextSpan(
      text: "قَيِّمًا لِيُنْذِرَ بَأْسًا شَدِيدًا مِنْ لَدُنْهُ وَيُبَشِّرَ الْمُؤْمِنِين  ٦ الَّذِينَ يَعْمَلُونَ الصَّالِحَاتِ أَنَّ لَهُمْ أَجْرًا حَسَنًا",
    ));
    spans.add(
      TextSpan(
          text: "قَيِّمًا لِيُنْذِرَ بَأْسًا شَدِيدًا مِنْ لَدُنْهُ وَيُبَشِّرَ الْمُؤْمِنِينَ الَّذِينَ يَعْمَلُونَ الصَّالِحَاتِ أَنَّ لَهُمْ أَجْرًا حَسَنًا",
          recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
            ..onTap = () {
              print("click on me");
            }),
    );
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      spans.add(TextSpan(
        text: "قَيِّمًا لِيُنْذِرَ بَأْسًا شَدِيدًا مِنْ لَدُنْهُ وَيُبَشِّرَ الْمُؤْمِنِينَ الَّذِينَ يَعْمَلُونَ الصَّالِحَاتِ أَنَّ لَهُمْ أَجْرًا حَسَنًا",
      ));
    }

    return spans;
  }
```

WITH NUMBER
[image: WITH NUMBER]

WITHOUT NUMBER
[image: WITHOUT NUMBER]